# Rake Clear tmp is taking too long

Tags: ruby-on-rails, caching, rake, tmp

This is a rails app, when I tried to execute `rake tmp:clear` ,it is taking too long (about 45 minutes have passed and yet the task is not finished!). I was to ask is there a possibility that it is caused by the server generating the tmp?

This project is on Linode production server.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Try the following:

Run rails console on server by `rails console`

and then

`Rails.cache.clear`

Then you should see the cache clear, and you can quit console. This will have the same effect as clearing tmp.

Comment: Im not sure why, but I have to wait very very long period and it just seems stuck there and not able to clear the cache. I do know the method you mentioned, but no luck, seems not working for me...